# What's your favourite ReSharper's plugins, what is still missing in?

Tags: resharper

I'm new in ReSharper - I found it very useful but also noticed some gaps I'd like to fill.

I wonder to know
1) what **ReSharper's plugins you use**.
2) what **missing functionalities you are extremely interested** to have in inside?

From my side:

**PLUGINS:**
A) spell check my XML comments  (have to use [Agent Smith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/))

**LACK OF FUNCTIONALITIES**
a) numbered bookmarking (Deplhi-like)   (forced to use [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/Bookmarks.aspx))
b) right align variables / operands (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286806/resharper-formatting-align-equal-operands))
c) possibility to collapse all projects in solution browser (again need use DPack)

Comment: @Binary Worrier: 
I dont think this is duplication of question you edited!
I've asked about favourite plugins which fills R# gaps (NOT EXISTING functionality) - quoted question asked about favourite (EXISTING) functinoality

Answer (score 7):

There's one plugin for R# that is completely different from any other plugins. It's called [WhySharper](http://code.google.com/p/whysharper/) and it dovetails R# and this very site, stackoverflow.

Quite often, people ask questions as "why R# recommends this" and "why R# suggests that". With [WhySharper](http://code.google.com/p/whysharper/) installed, you can quickly get complete and detailed explanations to pretty much *anything* - directly from your Visual Studio! - or ask for an explanation if it's missing.

A bit more details at my blog [here](http://codevanced.net/post/Whysharper.aspx).

Comment: Looks like they implemented this as a feature in R# 6

Comment: Yeah, great news - they will provide much better support than I could have ever hoped for!

Answer (score 4):

[StyleCop for ReSharper](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/) provides Alt + Return correction of [StyleCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/) guideline violations.

Answer (score 2):

[AgentJohnson](http://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/) and [AgentSmith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/) provide lots of goodies to R#; I tried also a plugin for NHibernate HBMs but is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

- numbered bookmarking -- will be in ReSharper 5
- right align variables / operands -- unlikely
- possibility to collapse all projects in solution browser -- available since ReSharper 4.5

Comment: Thanks for response - re collapsing - I've really missed it! Thanks
Re ver 5 - what's your release time estimation? 
And - is it somewhere planned features list available?