# Formatting declaration of constant strings

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

Is there a possibility to format constants? Turn this

```
public const string SHORT_CONST = "MyShortConst";
public const string QUITE_LONG_CONST = "MyQuiteLongConst";
```

into this

```
public const string SHORT_CONST      = "MyShortConst";
public const string QUITE_LONG_CONST = "MyQuiteLongConst";
```

Comment: Check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286806/resharper-formatting-align-equal-operands). Might be outdated though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Code alignment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd?SRC=VSIDE) extension for Visual Studio, this will allow you to align on the `=`

Comment: Quite nice, alighning by "=" is almost exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid code, it just may be that your editor automatically justifies the test when you type the `;` at the end of the line