# Code formatting for modified parts only

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-formatting

I'm looking for a way to format only modified parts of code in Visual Studio, specifically for Visual Studio 2013. I've got myself tangled in the habit of making regular use of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> to format the code of an entire file. Because of this option I've become rather lazy in writing correctly formatted code.

My co-workers have a neat code-alignment method to make code more readable (C# example):

```
var book = new Book()
{
    Name = "The adventures of John",
    Author = "John Doe",
    Category = "Adventure",
    Publisher = "Acme"
}
```

To:

```
var book = new Book()
{
    Name      = "The adventures of John",
    Author    = "John Doe",
    Category  = "Adventure",
    Publisher = "Acme"
}
```

My problem is is that using the code-formatting feature formats the code to its initial state (the first code sample). I'm aware that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> formats only selected ranges of code, but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Is there any plugin that provides me with the ability to format code that I modified, the code parts that are indicated with yellow and green bars in the scrollbar?

[image: Visual Studio scrollbar indicators]

Comment: Is it me or do the two code blocks look exactly the same?

Comment: @LukkhaCoder The assignments are aligned on the equals symbol, perhaps your browser shows them differently. It's just a small example.

Answer (score 0):

this one.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd

and this one

http://www.codealignment.com/

You can try this: Code Alignment

It supports

Align by... (Dialog)
Align by position... (Dialog)
Align by Equals
Align by m_
Align by "
Align by .
Align by Space

similar topic here:
[ReSharper formatting: align equal operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286806/resharper-formatting-align-equal-operands)

Comment: That is not really what I was asking for

Comment: oh. so you just dont want visual studio show it as yellow?  if this is the case. I think maybe not. but if you using the code alignment tool. you and your cowork will both happy-- the format result is same. so vs2010 always show it as green.

Comment: They use Code Alignment, and I do to sometimes. But my issue is about code-formatting counteracting with the code-alignment, and I was hoping that there's a feature out there that support code-formatting for modified code only.