# Create spaces when declaration code in resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I am using ReSharper 9 and I want to know have any ways I can convert this code

```
public static string GetMapsOfMapPaid = "gMMP";
public static string GetMapsOfTopAttackedCount = "gMAC";
```

to this:

```
public static string GetMapsOfMapPaid             = "gMMP";
public static string GetMapsOfTopAttackedCount    = "gMAC";
```

Comment: Why you want to do that? it takes more memory and has no use whatsoever.

Comment: @Prajwal Takes more memory? Are we living in 1990 still? I really hope you aren't compressing your source code to save a few bytes of diskspace.

Comment: @Rob please do tell me the use of adding more space? readability?

Comment: @Prajwal Readability is subjective, my point is saying you shouldn't format code *because it takes more memory* is not really an argument against it.

Comment: @Rob I see no point in doing it. That's why I said it is waste of memory. let it be a byte or two.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286806/resharper-formatting-align-equal-operands

Comment: @Prajwal it maybe will cost you a little memory, but it still help your code more clearly and readability, right?

Comment: It is not necessary to edit your post and add "Solved", as it would invalidate the purpose of Stack Overflow as a question and answer site (it would no longer be a question). If you feel this question warrants a proper answer, you can post one. Or if, as in this case, you identify a duplicate, you can flag this post as a duplicate.