# Align const assignments in Visual Studio using .editorconfig

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

Does anyone know whether it's possible to align const assignments in Visual Studio using .editorconfig.

Just for clarity:

```
class MyConstants {
    public const string FirstConst = "First constant";
    public const string SecondLongerConstant = "Second longer constant";
}
```

Should be aligned like this:

```
class MyConstants {
    public const string FirstConst           = "First constant";
    public const string SecondLongerConstant = "Second longer constant";
}
```

When I align them manually right now and reformat the file, the code is reset back to the first example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286806/resharper-formatting-align-equal-operands may be of interest.

Comment: [But why?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEZWYXPvmS8). I hate it when people do this. And what if another developer adds `ThirdEvenLongerConstant`, they'll touch all the lines in that file (at least, if you want the rule still to apply). That'll mess up your revision history, _and_ the readability of that file. Sure, it looks fancy, but is it useful? But I know you're not asking for feedback.

Comment: @CodeCaster You have a good point there. Thanks for your feedback on that one. It's always this thing about readability vs all the others.

Answer (score 0):

In response to: "When I align them manually right now and reformat the file, the code is reset back to the first example".

This won't align them for you, but it does prevent [Code Cleanup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022#apply-code-styles) from resetting them back to your first example (tested in Visual Studio 2022 17.1.1).

```
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = ignore
```

For anyone stumbling across this in search of a more general solution be aware that this works for the question example but does not work for something like assigning to a property or field in a constructor. More information available [here](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/editorconfig-reference-for-c-developers).